# How to split a column into multiple columns based on string length?

Tags: python, string, split

I'm a programming novice, so please excuse this basic question.

I have a csv file where each record is just one long string with no delimiters, e.g. 'A01BC234'. I want to split this into 4 separate columns as follows: 'A', '01', 'BC', '234'. Every record has the same string length, and I need to split it at the same place: i.e. in the above example, Column 1 will always have 1 character, Column 2 will have 2, Column 3 will have 2 and Column 4 will have 3.

Is there a simple way to do this with a function in python? I looked up the documentation for `split()`, but looks like needs a delimiter.

Comment: If you are sure about the length of each column value then simply make slices of string. 
e.g Let a is your string then value of column 1 and column 2 will be a[0] and a[1:3] respectively.

Comment: are the resulting column lengths: 1,2,2,3

Answer (score 1):

The `re.findall` function comes in handy here:

```
row = 'A01BC234'
parts = re.findall(r'([A-Z])([0-9]{2})([A-Z]{2})([0-9]{3})', row)
print(parts)
```

This prints the following tuple (in a list of element):

```
[('A', '01', 'BC', '234')]
```

**Edit:**

We could also accomplish the same result using string slicing:

```
x = 'A01BC234'
parts = [x[:1], x[1:3], x[3:5], x[5:]]
print(parts)  # ['A', '01', 'BC', '234']
```

This might outperform the regex version as it relies only on the base string functions.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Biegeleisen this worked beautifully. Given I have several thousand rows in my csv, this took a while to complete. Is there a computationally less expensive way to do this at scale?

Comment: @Akshay Check my updated answer for a version which avoids regex.

Comment: Thank you again Tim! This worked well. Hamza, I see you had hinted at this solution as well. The only challenge I'm facing now is actually applying this to every row of a pandas dataframe (name: df). My input is a csv file with ~500,000 rows and 1 column, where each row is a string in the above format. My desired output after the slicing, is a pandas dataframe with 4 columns. I tried using a for loop with iterrows() to enter each row, apply this rule, and append the result to a new dataframe, but didn't work. I also tried list comprehensions, but failed again. Any advice will be most helpful!